# select multiple tables with MySql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have 4 tables and I want to display the results for all of them. However, I am having the problem in retrieving the data from these tables. For all tables, they are having the same key which is called `applicantId` and I want to join all tables with this key.

Also, this is the account base website that I am building on. So there will be a unique `accountId` for these data. This means that a person can only view their own data within their account.

**The problem** I am having now is that I not able to get the data from MySql.

These are my tables below:

account table: 
[image]

applicantpersonaldetails table:
[image]

employementdetails table:
[image]

existingbankproducts table: 
[image]

This is my code in php:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        <?php

                        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails,employementdetails,existingbankproducts "
                                . "WHERE applicantpersonaldetails.ApplicantID = employementdetails.ApplicantID "
                                . "= existingbankproducts.applicantID "
                                . "and applicantpersonaldetails.AccountID ='{$accountId}'");
                        $stmt->execute();

                        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                extract($row);
                                ?>
<?php
                            }
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
```

The $`accountId` is get it after I login.

Comment: Why don't you fetch data using join?

Comment: What errors are you getting..? Have you tried executing query directly in phpMyAdmin..?

Comment: the problem is I am not getting the data from mysql, 0 rows of data was shown

Answer (score 0):

u should join the tables together while selecting them, this means that while the tables still remain different u select them as a unique table using the "id" field as primary key. here is some documentation about the join rule
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `AND`.

This should work.

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails,employementdetails,existingbankproducts "
    . "WHERE applicantpersonaldetails.ApplicantID = employementdetails.ApplicantID "
    . "and applicantpersonaldetails.ApplicantID = existingbankproducts.applicantID "
    . "and applicantpersonaldetails.AccountID ='{$accountId}'");
```

By the way I suggest you to use `JOIN` since selecting from multiple tables makes the statement very unclear. Furthermore using aliases would be a good idea since your table names are pretty long.

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails apd "
    . "JOIN employementdetails ed ON apd.ApplicantID = ed.ApplicantID "
    . "JOIN existingbankproducts ebp ON apb.ApplicantID = ebp.ApplicantID "
    . "WHERE apd.AccountID ='{$accountId}'");
```